# What provides my react components with the history object?

Tags: reactjs

Why is it enough to write:

```
const SearchForm = ({ history }) => {}
```

while defining my components to get access to the history object in react? Inside my index.js (app) i dont drill down the history object and it doesent occur in my routes too.

Here is my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from 'themes/default.theme';
import GlobalStyles from 'assets/style/Global.style';
import AuthProvider from 'context/AuthProvider';
import Routes from './router';
import store from './frontend/store.js'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />              
      <BrowserRouter>               
         <AuthProvider>             
          <Routes />
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store ={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Edit: i use the searchform inside search.js:

```
const SearchArea = ({ searchTitleStyle, searchDescriptionStyle }) => {
  return (
    <BannerWrapper>
      <GlideCarousel
        controls={true}
        options={{ gap: 0, autoplay: 5000, animationDuration: 1000 }}
        bullets={true}
        numberOfBullets={1}
      >
        <>
          <GlideSlide>
            <img src={bannerBg1} alt="Banner 1" />
          </GlideSlide>
          
        </>
      </GlideCarousel>

      <Container>
        <SearchWrapper>
          <Heading
            {...searchTitleStyle}
            content="Wiederverwendung statt Neuproduktion"
          />
          <Text
            {...searchDescriptionStyle}
            content="            "
          />
          <SearchForm />
        </SearchWrapper>
      </Container>
    </BannerWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Show how you use `<SearchForm/>` because that matters.  You either get it given to you by `Route` as a prop https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props or you use `useHistory` which probably leverages `useContext` under the hood.

Comment: i edited my post. but i am not using useHistory here too.. The searchare is usend inside home.js. Home.js does give it a lyoutcontext, But it seems like there is no "history" too (searched with the ide)